Postgres query duration peaks
We have docker containers (12) running on-prem machines, one of them is a postgres DB, on the same query we sometimes get peaks of 30+ seconds for a query that most of the time takes 2 seconds.
The graph below displays the table select duration (so we assume it is not network/server/pools latency)
We are trying to eliminate options here when looking for the cause of this temporary failure, should i be checking something specific in postges ? we use the default configuration.
Can it be that postgres chooses different query strategy once in a while that has such an effect on performance? (we see different results on the exact same data sometimes)
EDIT-1 query runs on view, ( not Materialized View)


It can depends from values in query, statistic and data cardinality. I suggest you to post the query plan to investigate.

A default configuration gives you default performance. Not high performance.

Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this SQL statement, the statement itself and all ddl for the tables and indexes involved? All in plain text

Your db machine config (CPU, RAM, disk) config would be good also!

It isn't clear what your graph is showing.  Is that latency measured inside the database or at the client or somewhere else?  Setting up autoexplain in the db server to log the plans of slow queries can let you see if plan changes are the culprit.

The graph is showing traces from grafana agent (the duration of a specific api call)

My question is not about how to optimize, but more a high-level question to help me focus in the right direction, does it make sense for the same query to run most of the time with 2sec duration, and sometimes 50sec duration ?
